# Use cata with Sum of functors

Tags: haskell, recursion-schemes

I'm playing with [`Data.Fix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-fix-0.0.3/docs/Data-Fix.html) and [`Data.Functor.Sum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Sum.html), and trying to use [`cata`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-fix-0.0.3/docs/Data-Fix.html#v:cata) with sum of functors, then ran into an issue that code didn't type check. But I'm not sure how I can make it type check.

Here is the code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

import Data.Fix (Fix(Fix), cata)
import Data.Functor.Sum (Sum(InL, InR))
import Prelude hiding (succ)

class (Functor f, Functor g) => IsPartOf f g where
    inj :: f a -> g a
    app :: (f a -> a) -> (g a -> a)
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Functor f => IsPartOf f f where
    inj = id
    app = id
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (Functor f, Functor g) => IsPartOf f (Sum f g) where
    inj = InL
    app f (InL l) = f l
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (Functor f, Functor g, Functor h, IsPartOf f g) => IsPartOf f (Sum h g) where
    inj = InR . inj
    app f (InR r) = app f r

data Zero e = Zero deriving Functor
data Succ e = Succ e deriving Functor
data Add e = Add e e deriving Functor

type Expr = Sum Zero (Sum Succ Add)

zero :: Fix Expr
zero = Fix (inj Zero)

succ :: Fix Expr -> Fix Expr
succ = Fix . inj . Succ

add :: Fix Expr -> Fix Expr -> Fix Expr
add = ((Fix . inj) .) . Add

class Value f where
    value :: Num a => f a -> a
instance Value Zero where
    value _ = 0
instance Value Succ where
    value (Succ e) = 1 + e
instance Value Add where
    value (Add e1 e2) = e1 + e2
{-
instance (Value f, Value g) => Value (Sum f g) where
    value (InL f) = value f
    value (InR g) = value g
-}
```

First, I have three functors `Zero`, `Succ` and `Add`. I combined them using `Sum` and defined `type Expr = Sum Zero (Sum Succ Add)`.

I also have `Value` class to convert each functor to a number. Since I don't want to write an instance of `Value` for `Sum` by myself, I introduced `IsPartOf` class that knows how to construct a sum of functors (`inj`) and how to apply a function for an inner functor to an outer functor (`app`).

But when I try to use them like `cata (app value) (succ zero)`, GHC says it doesn't type check.

```
*Main> cata (app value) (succ zero)

<interactive>:10:7:
    Overlapping instances for IsPartOf f0 Expr
      arising from a use of ‘app’
    Matching instances:
      instance [overlappable] (Functor f, Functor g, Functor h,
                               IsPartOf f g) =>
                              IsPartOf f (Sum h g)
        -- Defined at min.hs:16:31
      instance [overlappable] Functor f => IsPartOf f f
        -- Defined at min.hs:10:31
      instance [overlappable] (Functor f, Functor g) =>
                              IsPartOf f (Sum f g)
        -- Defined at min.hs:13:31
    (The choice depends on the instantiation of ‘f0’
     To pick the first instance above, use IncoherentInstances
     when compiling the other instance declarations)
    In the first argument of ‘cata’, namely ‘(app value)’
    In the expression: cata (app value) (succ zero)
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = cata (app value) (succ zero)

<interactive>:10:11:
    Could not deduce (Value f0) arising from a use of ‘value’
    from the context (Num a)
      bound by the inferred type of it :: Num a => a
      at <interactive>:10:1-28
    The type variable ‘f0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Value Add -- Defined at min.hs:41:10
      instance Value Succ -- Defined at min.hs:39:10
      instance Value Zero -- Defined at min.hs:37:10
    In the first argument of ‘app’, namely ‘value’
    In the first argument of ‘cata’, namely ‘(app value)’
    In the expression: cata (app value) (succ zero)
```

Why GHC doesn't find a proper instance? How can I make this type check, or what is a proper way to express this idea?

I tried this with GHC 7.10.3.

Comment: The compiler says `the choice depends on the instantiation of 'f0'`. Your use of `value`, being of type `(Value f, Num a) => f a -> a`, gives no hint as to which implementation of `app` should be used. Scatter some type annotations in there and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Now I think I understand it. I cannot give a type annotation to `value` in `cata (app value) (succ zero)` because `Expr` isn't an instance of `Value`, not like I can do `cata (app (value :: Num a => Zero a -> a)) (Fix Zero)`. So what I'm trying to do here is to define an instance of `Value` for `Expr` automatically. I guess I can do it with TH, but are there any ways to do it without TH?

Comment: Hold on, why can't you write that? Looks correct to me

Comment: Do you mean I can write `cata (app (value :: Num a => Expr a -> a)) (succ zero)`?

Comment: Yes, and it didn't type check.

Comment: Oh, I see why it didn't typecheck - you've commented out your instance of `Value (Sum f g)`

Comment: That's right. And as I explained in the question, I'm looking for a way to apply `value` to `Fix Expr` using `cata` without manually defining this instance.